# How to install specific version of Go in Ubuntu using snap

Tags: go, ubuntu, snap

Trying to install go version 1.16 using snap but not able to. can someone help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. you can run snap info go, which gives you a list of go versions.

   ```
   `sudo snap info go`
   ```
2. Then you can install your preferred version with --channel like this.

   `sudo snap install go --channel=1.6/stable --classic`

This will also work for upgrade / downgrade to specific version after installation. For example you want to downgrade from 1.17 go version to 1.16

```
  `sudo snap refresh go --channel=1.6/stable --classic`
```